# Does a Vietnamese passport holder need a transit visa to stay in the Kuwait City airport for 12 hours

Tags: transit-visas

I travel on a Vietnamese passport and will arrive in Kuwait City airport on Kuwait Airways for a 12 hour layover before boarding a KLM flight to Amsterdam. The layover period is from 1:30 PM to 1:30 AM. Will I need a transit visa to remain in the airport for those 12 hours ?

Comment: Are both flights on the same ticket, in this case meaning that you do not have to collect and re-check your luggage?